# Curl и редирект 307

Tags: php, curl

Мне нужно загрузить изображение по адресу https://fast.just.ru/xl_pics/330947.jpg. Пытаюсь сделать это через библиотеку curl. Но выдает http_code = 307. 
Мой скрипт выглядит так:

```
function curl_sync($url) {
  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 15);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  $output = curl_getinfo($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($output);
  echo "<pre>";

  return $result;
}
```

Вот ответ:

```
Array
(
[url] => https://fast.just.ru/xl_pics/330947.jpg
[content_type] => 
[http_code] => 307
[header_size] => 19299
[request_size] => 3709
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 0
[redirect_count] => 20
[total_time] => 0.922
[namelookup_time] => 0
[connect_time] => 0
[pretransfer_time] => 0
[size_upload] => 0
[size_download] => 0
[speed_download] => 0
[speed_upload] => 0
[download_content_length] => 0
[upload_content_length] => -1
[starttransfer_time] => 0.031
[redirect_time] => 0.891
[redirect_url] => 
[primary_ip] => 185.203.72.133
[certinfo] => Array
    (
    )

[primary_port] => 443
[local_ip] => 192.168.0.24
[local_port] => 27860
)
```

Можете подсказать в чем проблема?

Comment: А в чём проблема? Вас перенаправляют на другой ресурс. Вот как узнаете адрес другого ресурса - пишите.

Comment: Curl с опцией CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION должен следовать любому перенаправлению. Но этого не происходит. Я открыл эту ссылку в браузере, затем в инспекторе кода посмотрел заголовки - при первом запросе выдается код 307, затем сразу же картинка открывается с кодом 200, но url такой же как и при первом запросе...

Comment: Возможно, что при первом редиректе выдаются cokies или заголовки, которые при переходе уже выдают код 200

Comment: @aleks_sk получилось решить?